# Macros on related record(s)

Tags: macros

Can macros be utilized to update related records as well? For example, i have a Case record and a macro on that case record which performs some actions (send email, create task, etc)
What if i want to update a parent record (subscription custom object)? Can macros support this or are they used only in the one record used ?